# Как сделать, чтобы таймер не сбрасывался?

Tags: таймер, javascript

Сейчас имеется такой код:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

var Timer;

var TotalSeconds;

function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time) {

Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);

TotalSeconds = Time;

UpdateTimer()

window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);

}

function Tick() {

if (TotalSeconds <= 0) {

TotalSeconds = 7200;

}

TotalSeconds -= 1;

UpdateTimer()

window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);

}

function UpdateTimer() {

var Seconds = TotalSeconds;

var Days = Math.floor(Seconds / 86400);

Seconds -= Days * 86400;

var Hours = Math.floor(Seconds / 3600);

Seconds -= Hours * (3600);

var Minutes = Math.floor(Seconds / 60);

Seconds -= Minutes * (60);

var TimeStr = ((Days > 0) ? Days + " days " : "") + LeadingZero(Hours) + ":" +

LeadingZero(Minutes) + ":" + LeadingZero(Seconds)

Timer.innerHTML = TimeStr;

}

function LeadingZero(Time) {

return (Time < 10) ? "0" + Time : + Time;

}

</script>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body onload='CreateTimer("timer", 5)';>

<div id='timer' />

</body>

</html>
```

Он отсчитывает каждые 2ч. Но проблема - если обновить страницу, то таймер сбрасывается. Как это исправить?..

Comment: отсчитывайте от даты.

Answer (score 1):

Вчитываться в код  не стал...

Время можно начать считать от даты установленной у пользователя.

var _date = new Date();

Отсчет можно от этого времени начать.

Или от серверного, а это уже на событие window.onload = function () {делаете ajax запрос серверу и получаете время, а начинаете отсчет} или же сразу на php выводить.

А можно и время в куках сохранять..

Answer (score 0):

Преверять время на сервере, а не на клиенте.
Ну и выставлять нужное значение при открытии страницы.